# Pandas - split columns with default values if no delimiter present

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have below dataframe and I am trying to split 'name' column into first_name and last_name on the basis of space however for some names there is no delimiter and in such cases I want to take the value in last name and have blank in first name.

One possible way is to iterate over all the rows and use if-else condition over each row however as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas).

*"Iteration in Pandas is an anti-pattern and is something you should only do when you have exhausted every other option."* so I am looking for a way to achieve this in Pandas.

```py
names_df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
print(names_df)
names_df[['first_name', 'last_name']] = names_df['name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
print(names_df)
```

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

```
order_id      name        product_id  product_price
    0        Thanos         Ipad        800
    1        Hulk           AC          400
    2        C America      Ipad        760
    3        Black Panther  IPhone      1100
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
first_name   last_name   
              Thanos
              Hulk
   C          America
  Black       Panther
```

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? For me the code seems to work, however everything is added to the first_name column and only the last two have a last name. (pandas version 1.0.0)

Comment: @ScootCork I am using 1.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I was able to come up with, not sure if it is the most optimal one but it works

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Thanos', 'Hulk', 'Black Panther', 'C Amarica']})                                    

def split_name(name): 
    split_name = name.split(' ') 
    return split_name if len(split_name) == 2 else ['', split_name[0]]

pd.DataFrame(df.name.apply(split_name).tolist(), columns=['first_name', 'last_name'])

  first_name last_name
0               Thanos
1                 Hulk
2      Black   Panther
3          C   Amarica
```

Answer (score 4):

First split and then reverse internal list using `str[::-1]`

```
df[['last_name','first_name']] = df.name.str.split().str[::-1].apply(pd.Series).fillna('')

df
            name last_name first_name
0         Thanos    Thanos        
1           Hulk      Hulk        
2      C America   America          C
3  Black Panther   Panther      Black
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) along with the named regex capturing groups to extract the first and last name from the name column:

```
df1 = names_df['name'].str.extract(r'(?P<First_Name>\w+)\s(?P<Last_Name>\w+)')
df1['Last_Name'] = df1['Last_Name'].fillna(names_df['name'])
```

---

```
# print(df1)
  First_Name Last_Name
0        NaN    Thanos
1        NaN      Hulk
2          C   America
3      Black   Panther
```